# Passing JSON data to another function as parameter ... not passing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

PHP script (AJAX is calling this) (within this is this variable):

```
 $name_and_id = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " (" . $row['id'] . ")";
```

passed back like:

```
$datarr = array();
$datarr[] = array('name_and_id' => $name_and_id);
echo json_encode($datarr);
```

JSON successfully accepts like:

```
$.each(data, function(k, v){
  v = v.name_and_id;
...
htmlStr += '<tr onclick="shrow(' + x + ',' + v + ',' + z + ')">'
... populates a div
```

This loads correctly, but when I click on that `tr` the request doesn't complete ... console says throwing an error at `v` ...

Comment: Could you please show us the whole code example?

Comment: And how does the `function` above looks like?

Comment: `"<tr onclick=\"show('" + x + "','" + v + "','" + z + "')\">"` (but this is not safe)

Comment: @Caramiriel bind the function to tr externally? Give tr an id ...?

Comment: there isn't much we can do without the full js error message and the generated markup of the `<tr>`